# Shell script to enumerate the (already existing) LDAP group called "VPN Users"

Tags: ldap, shell, openldap, shell-scripting

I am new to LDAP and learning about the ldapsearch and ldap in general. Would like to write a shell script that enumerate the (already existing) LDAP group "VPN Users", then get all user "samaccountname" (e.g.joe.smith). Can someone please help? I've tried to do it but seems like my ldapsearch has errors:

```
ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -x -b (&(objectCategory=group)(cn=VPN Users))
```

Edit - Sorry about that. I made some progress and now at least cat get some data from the LDAP server by running something like this:

```
echo -n 'password' |
ldapsearch -y pass.txt -h [IP here] -b "ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=x" -x `
 -D "cn=user,ou=test,ou=x,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=xx" `
 -W "(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*) (memberOf=cn=VPN Users,ou=test,ou=x,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=xx))" `
 -y /dev/fd/0
```

But I would like it to:

- enumerate the (already existing) LDAP group "VPN Users"
- get all user "samaccountname" (e.g. joe.smith, etc.)

Thanks

Comment: Or this ldapsearch -h [remote IP here] -x -b "ou=test dc=unit,dc=dev,dc=net" "(&(objectCategory=group))"

Comment: Please also provide the error you are encountering.

Comment: Sorry about that. I made some progress and now at least cat get some data from the LDAP server by running something like this: 
echo -n 'password' | ldapsearch -y pass.txt -h [IP here] -b "ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=x" -x -D "cn=user,ou=test,ou=x,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=xx" -W "(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*) (memberOf=cn=VPN Users,ou=test,ou=x,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=xx))" -y /dev/fd/0

But I would like it to:

# enumerate the (already existing) LDAP group "VPN Users"
## get all user "samaccountname" (e.g. joe.smith, etc.)

Comment: Please edit provided information into your question.

Comment: I did!
Edit - Sorry about that. I made some progress and now at least cat get some data from the LDAP server by running something like this: echo -n 'password' | ldapsearch -y pass.txt -h [IP here] -b "ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=x" -x -D "cn=user,ou=test,ou=x,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=xx" -W "(&(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*) (memberOf=cn=VPN Users,ou=test,ou=x,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=xx))" -y /dev/fd/0 But I would like it to: # enumerate the (already existing) LDAP group "VPN Users" ## get all user "samaccountname" (e.g. joe.smith, etc.)

Comment: Please refactor your question to something readable by a human.

Comment: `... seems like my ldapsearch has errors:` - Including the errors would make it a lot easier to actually tell you what the problem is.  The answer is often found in the error.

Answer (score 0):

The expression to use in your query would be something like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf="VPN Users")) attrs=sAMAccountName
```

Finally:

```
ldapsearch -y pass.txt -h [IP here] -b "ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=x"
 -D "cn=user,ou=test,ou=x,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x,dc=xx" `
 -W "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf="VPN Users")) attrs=sAMAccountName -y /dev/fd/0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something maintaining the `memberOf` attribute (e.g. slapd-memberOf):

```
ldapsearch -h ldap.example.com -b ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com \  
    -D  cn=user,ou=accounts,dc=example,dc=com -W  -y password.txt \
    "(&(memberOf=cn=VPN Users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)(sAMAccountName=*))" \
    sAMAccountName
```

You can pipe the output through `sed` if your interested in just the values, e.g.

```
| sed -n 's/^sAMAccountName: //p'
```

---

`-y` needs the password to be exact. Most text editors including `vim` will insert a trailing newline (`\n`). This must be removed, e.g. `truncate -s -1 password.txt`.